# Can't get Phoenix link route to work

Tags: routes, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a model for 'Radios' and on my home page `(template/page/index.html.eex)` I am pulling in the last recorded.  This works fine, but I am struggling to get the link to work to go through to the show page `(template/radio/show.html.eex)` for that specific record.

In the console I get:

```
== Compilation error on file web/controllers/radio_controller.ex ==
** (CompileError) web/controllers/radio_controller.ex:31: undefined function last_radio/0
```

A lot of examples on line use @conn:

`<%= link "Show", to: radio_path(@conn, :show, radio), class: "button" %>`

And I've tried to change this to my query of `last_radio`:

`<%= link "Show", to: radio_path(@last_radio, :show, radio), class: "button" %>`

But that doesn't work.

Nor does:

`<%= link "Show", to: radio_path(@conn, :show, last_radio), class: "button" %>`

*radio_controller*

```
defmodule Radios.RadioController do
  use Radios.Web, :controller

  alias Radios.Radio

  def index(conn, _params) do
    radios = Repo.all(Radio)
    render conn, "index.html"
  end

  def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    radio = Repo.get!(Radio, id)
    render(conn, "show.html", radio: radio)
  end
```

*page_controller*

```
defmodule Radios.PageController do
  use Radios.Web, :controller

  alias Radios.Radio


  def index(conn, _params) do
    last_radio = Radio |> last |> Repo.one
    #|> Radio.sorted
    #|> Radios.Repo.one
    render(conn, "index.html", last_radio: last_radio)

  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error is on line 31, however, you the code you provided is showing less than 31 lines. Is the controller longer than that?

Comment: It is yes, but your answer below has fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use bindings from your controller in a template, you need to prefix them with `@`. So, for links in your `templates/radio/` folder use:

```
<%= link "Show", to: radio_path(@conn, :show, @radio), class: "button" %>
```

and for `templates/page` use:

```
<%= link "Show", to: radio_path(@conn, :show, @last_radio), class: "button" %>
```

Additional Note:

If you render a partial from a template, the bindings from the calling template **do not** get passed to the partial. You need to handle them yourself. I'm adding this so it may save you some time in the future.

```
<%= render "my_partial", conn: @conn, radio: @radio %>
```